# Integral of maximum function

Tags: integration, functions, solution-verification, maxima-minima

I have a function $$\max(1,x)$$
The integral $$I = \int_{0}^{5}\max(1,x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\,dx + \int_{1}^{5}x\,dx = 
\left[x\right]_{0}^{1}+\left[\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_{1}^{5}=1+\frac{24}{2}=13$$

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Draw a graphical representation: you will see that it's the sum of the areas of 2 half squares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes,
$$x\in[0,5],\,\,\max(1,x)=\begin{cases}1&0\le x<1\\x&1\le x\le 5\end{cases}$$
which looks like:
[image]
Linked [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bncwcjaiey)